# How to configure JMS in JBoss EAP 7?

Tags: java, jms, jboss-eap-7

I have tired searching google and got like this. Those link are refer jboss eap 6.

1.How to configure JMS in jboss eap 7?

2.Is there Jboss eap 7 have in built-in JMS? or need configure manually?

3.sample Application using Jboss eap 7?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

After lots of struggle i got the answer.

In JBoss EAP 7 server supports Apache ActiveMQ Artemis. which are inbuilt in JBoss EAP 7 server, but some downloaded JBoss EAP 7 servers may not contain Apache ActiveMQ Artemis, by which you may not find **Messaging-ActiveMQ** in jboss subsystem. For this you need to configure manually in standalone.xml file.
Below follow the steps for configuration.

**Step-1**

Start JBoss EAP 7 server

**step-2**

•   Run add-user.bat file from cd /PATH/TO/JBoss-EAP-7.0/bin.

•   For linux server need to ./add-user.sh command.
After running a cmd will appear.

then a cmd will appear. here you need to add new application user.
Let your:

**username:** jmsuser,
**password:** jmsuser@123,
**user role:** guest

```
What type of user do you wish to add? 
 a) Management User (mgmt-users.properties) 
 b) Application User (application-users.properties)
(a): b

Enter the details of the new user to add.
Using realm 'ApplicationRealm' as discovered from the existing property files.
Username : jmsuser
User 'jmsuser' already exists and is enabled, would you like to... 
 a) Update the existing user password and roles 
 b) Disable the existing user 
 c) Type a new username
(a): a
Password recommendations are listed below. To modify these restrictions edit the add-user.properties configuration file.
 - The password should be different from the username
 - The password should not be one of the following restricted values {root, admin, administrator}
 - The password should contain at least 8 characters, 1 alphabetic character(s), 1 digit(s), 1 non-alphanumeric symbol(s)
Password : 
Re-enter Password : 
What groups do you want this user to belong to? (Please enter a comma separated list, or leave blank for none)[guest]: guest
Updated user 'jmsuser' to file '/Users/jsensharma/NotBackedUp/Installed/wildfly-10.0.0.CR3-SNAPSHOT/standalone/configuration/application-users.properties'
Updated user 'jmsuser' to file '/Users/jsensharma/NotBackedUp/Installed/wildfly-10.0.0.CR3-SNAPSHOT/domain/configuration/application-users.properties'
Updated user 'jmsuser' with groups guest to file '/Users/jsensharma/NotBackedUp/Installed/wildfly-10.0.0.CR3-SNAPSHOT/standalone/configuration/application-roles.properties'
Updated user 'jmsuser' with groups guest to file '/Users/jsensharma/NotBackedUp/Installed/wildfly-10.0.0.CR3-SNAPSHOT/domain/configuration/application-roles.properties'
Is this new user going to be used for one AS process to connect to another AS process? 
e.g. for a slave host controller connecting to the master or for a Remoting connection for server to server EJB calls.
yes/no? yes
To represent the user add the following to the server-identities definition <secret value="am1zdXNlckAxMjM=" />
```

**Setp-3**
 Creating a simple JMS Queue using the JBoss CLI command line utility. NOTE the JNDI name should contain “java:/jboss/exported” prefix or else the JMS queue will can not be looked up remotely.
let here your queue name is **TestQ**

```
$ cd /PATH/TO/JBoss-eap-7.0/bin
$ ./jboss-cli.sh -c

[standalone@localhost:9990 /] /subsystem=messaging-activemq/server=default/jms-queue=TestQ/:add(entries=["java:/jboss/exported/jms/queue/TestQ"])
  {"outcome" => "success"}

[standalone@localhost:9990 /] :reload
  {
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => undefined
  }
```

**step-4**
now check your **standalone.xml** file, whether below xml code generated or not, if not generated then copy the below code and paste it.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:1.0">
    <server name="default">
        <security-setting name="#">
            <role name="guest" delete-non-durable-queue="true" create-non-durable-queue="true" consume="true" send="true"/>
        </security-setting>
        <address-setting name="#" message-counter-history-day-limit="10" page-size-bytes="2097152" max-size-bytes="10485760" expiry-address="jms.queue.ExpiryQueue" dead-letter-address="jms.queue.DLQ"/>
        <http-connector name="http-connector" endpoint="http-acceptor" socket-binding="http"/>
        <http-connector name="http-connector-throughput" endpoint="http-acceptor-throughput" socket-binding="http">
            <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
        </http-connector>
        <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
        <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor" http-listener="default"/>
        <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor-throughput" http-listener="default">
            <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
            <param name="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
        </http-acceptor>
        <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
        <jms-queue name="ExpiryQueue" entries="java:/jms/queue/ExpiryQueue"/>
        <jms-queue name="DLQ" entries="java:/jms/queue/DLQ"/>

        <!-- Newly added JMS Queue is Here -->
        <jms-queue name="TestQ" entries="java:/jboss/exported/jms/queue/TestQ"/>

        <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory" entries="java:/ConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm"/>
        <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" connectors="http-connector"/>
        <pooled-connection-factory name="activemq-ra" transaction="xa" entries="java:/JmsXA java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm"/>
    </server>
</subsystem>
```

**Note:** If standalone.xml file doesn’t contain `<extension module="org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq"/>` inside `<extensions>` tag then you need to add manually this in standalone.xml file
[image]

**Step-5**
Now try to access admin console to check whether the queue is added or not.
URL - http://localhost:9990/console/App.html
[image]

Configuration Done.

**How to access JMS using JAVA**

Jars for Normal Standalone program

[image]

**OR**

Dependency for maven project
**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.jboss.quickstarts.eap</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-helloworld-jms</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.0.GA</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>JBoss EAP Quickstart: helloworld-jms</name>
    <description>helloworld-jms: Helloworld JMS external producer/consumer client</description>
    <url>http://www.jboss.org/products/eap</url>

    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>Apache License, Version 2.0</name>
            <distribution>repo</distribution>
            <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html</url>
        </license>
    </licenses>

    <!-- Activate JBoss Product Maven repository.

        NOTE: Configuring the Maven repository in the pom.xml file is not a recommended procedure
        and is only done here to make it easier to use the quickstarts.

        For more information about how to configure Maven for your application,
        see the section entitled 'Use the Maven Repository'
        in the Development Guide for Red Hat JBoss Enterprise Application Platform located here:

        https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en/jboss-enterprise-application-platform/
    -->
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jboss-enterprise-maven-repository</id>
            <url>https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>jboss-enterprise-maven-repository</id>
            <url>https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <properties>
        <!-- Explicitly declaring the source encoding eliminates the following message: -->
        <!-- [WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered
            resources, i.e. build is platform dependent! -->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <!-- EAP component version management BOM -->
        <version.jboss.bom.eap>7.0.0.GA</version.jboss.bom.eap>

        <!-- WildFly Maven plug-in to deploy your WAR to a local JBoss EAP container -->
        <version.wildfly.maven.plugin>1.0.2.Final</version.wildfly.maven.plugin>

        <!-- other plug-in versions -->
        <version.jar.plugin>2.2</version.jar.plugin>
        <version.exec.plugin>1.2.1</version.exec.plugin>

        <!-- maven-compiler-plugin -->
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- JBoss distributes a complete set of Java EE APIs including a Bill
                of Materials (BOM). A BOM specifies the versions of a "stack" (or a collection)
                of artifacts. We use this here so that we always get the correct versions
                of artifacts. Here we use the jboss-eap-javaee7 stack (you can
                read this as the JBoss stack of the Java EE APIs and related components.  -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.bom</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-eap-javaee7</artifactId>
                <version>${version.jboss.bom.eap}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.eap</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-jms-client-bom</artifactId>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.exec.plugin}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.jboss.as.quickstarts.jms.HelloWorldJMSClient1</mainClass>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <systemProperty>
                            <key>java.logging.config.file</key>
                            <value>./helloworld-jms-logging.properties</value>
                        </systemProperty>
                    </systemProperties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.jar.plugin}</version>
                <configuration>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- WildFly plug-in to deploy the WAR -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.wildfly.maven.plugin}</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**HelloWorldJMSProducer.java**

```
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.Destination;
import javax.jms.JMSContext;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

public class HelloWorldJMSProducer{

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(HelloWorldJMSProducer.class.getName());

    // Set up all the default values
    private static final String DEFAULT_MESSAGE = "Hello, World! successfull";
    private static final String DEFAULT_CONNECTION_FACTORY = "jms/RemoteConnectionFactory";
    private static final String DEFAULT_DESTINATION = "jms/queue/TestQ";
    private static final String DEFAULT_MESSAGE_COUNT = "1";
    private static final String DEFAULT_USERNAME = "jmsuser";
    private static final String DEFAULT_PASSWORD = "jmsuser@123";
    private static final String INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY = "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory";
    private static final String PROVIDER_URL = "http-remoting://127.0.0.1:8888";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Context namingContext = null;

        try {
            String userName = System.getProperty("username", DEFAULT_USERNAME);
            String password = System.getProperty("password", DEFAULT_PASSWORD);

            // Set up the namingContext for the JNDI lookup
            final Properties env = new Properties();
            env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY);
            env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, System.getProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL, PROVIDER_URL));
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, userName);
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
            namingContext = new InitialContext(env);

            // Perform the JNDI lookups
            String connectionFactoryString = System.getProperty("connection.factory", DEFAULT_CONNECTION_FACTORY);
            ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) namingContext.lookup(connectionFactoryString);

            String destinationString = System.getProperty("destination", DEFAULT_DESTINATION);
            Destination destination = (Destination) namingContext.lookup(destinationString);

            int count = Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("message.count", DEFAULT_MESSAGE_COUNT));
            String content = System.getProperty("message.content", DEFAULT_MESSAGE);

            try (JMSContext context = connectionFactory.createContext(userName, password)) {
                // Send the specified number of messages
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    context.createProducer().send(destination, content);
                }

                System.out.println("Sent...");
            }
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            log.severe(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            if (namingContext != null) {
                try {
                    namingContext.close();
                } catch (NamingException e) {
                    log.severe(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**HelloWorldJMSConsumer.java**

```
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.Destination;
import javax.jms.JMSConsumer;
import javax.jms.JMSContext;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

public class HelloWorldJMSConsumer {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(HelloWorldJMSConsumer.class.getName());

    // Set up all the default values
    private static final String DEFAULT_CONNECTION_FACTORY = "jms/RemoteConnectionFactory";
    private static final String DEFAULT_DESTINATION = "jms/queue/TestQ";
    private static final String DEFAULT_USERNAME = "jmsuser";
    private static final String DEFAULT_PASSWORD = "jmsuser@123";
    private static final String INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY = "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory";
    private static final String PROVIDER_URL = "http-remoting://127.0.0.1:8888";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Context namingContext = null;

        try {
            String userName = System.getProperty("username", DEFAULT_USERNAME);
            String password = System.getProperty("password", DEFAULT_PASSWORD);

            // Set up the namingContext for the JNDI lookup
            final Properties env = new Properties();
            env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY);
            env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, System.getProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL, PROVIDER_URL));
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, userName);
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
            namingContext = new InitialContext(env);

            // Perform the JNDI lookups
            String connectionFactoryString = System.getProperty("connection.factory", DEFAULT_CONNECTION_FACTORY);
            ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory) namingContext.lookup(connectionFactoryString);

            String destinationString = System.getProperty("destination", DEFAULT_DESTINATION);
            Destination destination = (Destination) namingContext.lookup(destinationString);

            try (JMSContext context = connectionFactory.createContext(userName, password)) {
                System.out.println("Received...");
                // Create the JMS consumer
                JMSConsumer consumer = context.createConsumer(destination);
                // Then receive the same number of messages that were sent
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    String text = consumer.receiveBody(String.class, 5000);
                    System.out.println(text);
                }

            }
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            log.severe(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            if (namingContext != null) {
                try {
                    namingContext.close();
                } catch (NamingException e) {
                    log.severe(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice one mate... Great Job

Comment: I have one quick question, I have working experience with Websphere App server and In WAS we use different port numbers for JMS communication, does this imply to the JBoss server as well? Can we configure this port number?

Comment: sorry, i don't have knowledge on this

Comment: Good answer, silly on getting closed as too broad.  I didnt need your answer, but wish I had found it yesterday when I went through all the same problems you did, lol - hence why I thinks its good as I believe it covered on everything I did.  I did make a point of using standalone-full.xml to make things easier though.

Comment: @JGlass, you missed it :)

Comment: @SangramBadi if i have already have the messaging-queue in jboss eap.how can i add queue and how to configure in jboss admin console?

Comment: Cant we just use standalone-full.xml which has all these already in it ?
Please see this video.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4XwVjX_Q33Y

I found it useful

Comment: Here is some sample code 
https://github.com/jboss-developer/jboss-eap-quickstarts/

Comment: What a nice thread, I am really thankful for your guidance. Regarding the ActiveMQ configuration, I had to run the `standalone-full.xml` or `standalone-full-ha.xml` configuration to be able to configure ActiveMq like you did. In the `standalone.xml` its not available and when I edit it manually, it will get overwritten whenever a restart the jboss server.

Answer (score 8):

See for example: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en/red-hat-jboss-enterprise-application-platform/7.0/paged/configuring-messaging/chapter-3-getting-started

When you use standalone-full.xml or standalone-full-ha.xml, then messaging in included in the configuration.

Comment: to start eap using standalone-full.xml: `./standalone.sh -c standalone-full.xml`

Comment: Yes see this video it explains 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4XwVjX_Q33Y

Comment: You can find sample jave code for clients or MDB at 
https://github.com/jboss-developer/jboss-eap-quickstarts/