# How to establish a JMS connection with EAP 7

Tags: jms, jboss-eap-7

After following all the steps for setting up a JMS client ( [How to configure JMS in JBoss EAP 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40015829/how-to-configure-jms-in-jboss-eap-7)),

I have the following lines of errors:

```
javax.naming.CommunicationException: WFNAM00018: Failed to connect to remote host [Root exception is java.io.IOException: JBREM000202: Abrupt close on Remoting connection 3c6a9a86 to /127.0.0.1:8080 of endpoint (anonymous) <13805618>]

Caused by: java.io.IOException: JBREM000202: Abrupt close on Remoting connection 3c6a9a86 to /127.0.0.1:8080 of endpoint (anonymous) <13805618>
```

Comment: Check the example  here: http://websystique.com/spring/spring-4-jms-activemq-example-with-jmslistener-enablejms/
https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Messaging+configuration

Comment: Aslo the quickstart helps : https://github.com/sgilda/wildfly-quickstart/tree/master/helloworld-jms